# Add pagination to table Angular 2

Tags: angular, datatable, pagination

I want to add pagination in the bottom of my own bootstrap table with angular
I don't want to use one of the examples of tables.
Can anyone help me ?

```
 <table class='table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive table-hover' id="table" style="margin-top: 2%">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Id boitier</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Id phase</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Power</th>
    <th colspan="3">Voltage</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Date</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Time</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Details</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Max</th>
    <th>Min</th>
    <th>Moy</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor='let cursen of cursens'>
    <td >{{cursen.id_boitier}}</td>
    <td>{{cursen.id_phase}}</td>
    <td>{{cursen.power}}</td>
    <td>{{cursen.voltage.Max}}</td><td>{{cursen.voltage.Min}}</td><td>{{cursen.voltage.Moy}}</td>
    <td>{{cursen.date  | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
    <td>{{cursen.date  | date:'HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
    <td><a (click)="onSelect(cursen)">alaa</a></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you have tried and where you failed.

Comment: What does "I don't want to use one of the examples of tables." mean?

Comment: That's mean that I don't want to install tables packages from npm

Comment: Hello @GünterZöchbauer , I just added the code of the table

Comment: You can use this pagination code https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination and implement a filter to take apart your data and choose a part according to current page number and give it to ngFor.

Comment: @BünyaminSarıgül , in the table , how can i specifiy items per page ??

Comment: For example, let say you want 3 items per page and cursens array is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]. Your filter should return cursens.slice(pageNo*3, pageNo*3+3) to ngFor. If pageNo=0, (0,3) => [1,2,3], pageNo=1 => [4,5,6], etc. ngFor will iterate over these arrays instead of full array.

Comment: You can also use [ng2-table](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap).

Answer (score -3):

Here is an example:

Pagination from [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination) and then

In the view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="cursen in cursens | pagination: pageNo * pageSize | limitTo: pageSize>
...
</tr>
```

In the js file:

```
app.filter('pagination', function()
{
 return function(input, start)
 {
  start = +start;
  return input.slice(start);
 };
});
```

Comment: I'm using Angular 2 !!

Comment: This is an example from web but you can do the same with angular2